# jquery: unchecking checkboxes only works one way

Tags: jquery

I have some checkboxes on my page. if the top checkbox is checked, it unchecks all the checkboxes below. that's good!

But I also want it reversed: when one of the below checkboxes (they are generated dynamically) is checked, it unchecks the top one.

this is what I tried:

```
 <table>
     <tr>
         <td>
             @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AllLangsChecked, new { onchange = "checkedChanged", @id = "langcheck" })
             <script>
                 $('.disableCheckboxes input:checkbox').change(function () {
                     $('.disableCheckboxes input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
                 })

                 $('#langcheck input:checkbox').change(function () {
                     $('#langcheck input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
                 })
             </script>
             <label>Sichtbar in allen Sprachen</label>
         </td>
     </tr>
     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.checkLangs.Count; i++)
     {
         <tr>
             <td>
                 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.checkLangs[i].Name)
                 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.checkLangs[i].LanguageId)
                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.checkLangs[i].isChecked, new { onchange = "checkedChanged" })
                 <label>@Model.checkLangs[i].Name</label>
             </td>
         </tr>
     }
 </table>
```

Again, the first part of the  works, its those lines, that fail:

```
             $('#langcheck input:checkbox').change(function () {
                 $('#langcheck input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
             })
```

So what I basically tried is giving the top-level checkbox an id: `langcheck`,
I added the eventlistener to my checkboxes and I am trying to fire the above script. But it fails with no error. Nothing is unchecked.

What can I do here?

Best,

J

EDIT:

I tried what you all suggested, ran my script at the bottom of the page, and edited it a little:

```
<script>
     $('.disableCheckboxes input:checkbox').change(function () {
         $('.disableCheckboxes input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
     })

     $(document).on("change", "input:checkbox:not(#langCheck)", function () {
         $('#langcheck input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
     })
 </script>
```

But this leads to the behavior now that only ever one checkbox is checkable.

What I wanted is to either check the top checkbox (Sichtbar in allen SPrachen = all languages). This shall uncheck all below checkboxes (and it did already)

While if ANY of the checkboxes below (with the languages) is checked, it unchecks JUST the first checkbox. I am a bit confused over how to do this with jQuery still...

[image]

EDIT 2:

```js
var selectCategory;
var inputSerch;

function checkedChanged() {
  alert("checkedChanged");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  selectCategory = $('#idVideoCategory');
  inputSerch = $('#idSearch');

  selectCategory.on('change', function() {
    UpdateVideoList();
  });

  inputSerch.on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      UpdateVideoList();
      return false;
    }
  });

});

function UpdateVideoList() {

  var oContent = $('#idVideoList');
  var iCategory = selectCategory.val();
  var sSearch = inputSerch.val();

  var url = "/de/Administration/Video/GetVideoList" + "?id=895&categoryId=" + iCategory + "&search=" + sSearch;

  Base.Ajax.LoadInContent(url, oContent);
}



function RemoveSelectedVideo() {
  var url = "/de/Administration/Video/RemoveSelectedVideo" + "?videoId=" + 895;
  window.location.href = url;
  /*Base.Ajax.Request(url, function(result) 
  {
      UpdateVideoList();        
  }
  );*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="langcheck" name="AllLangsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="AllLangsChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>Sichtbar in allen Sprachen</label>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="checkLangs_0__Name" name="checkLangs[0].Name" type="hidden" value="English">
        <input id="checkLangs_0__LanguageId" name="checkLangs[0].LanguageId" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input checked="checked" id="checkLangs_0__isChecked" name="checkLangs[0].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" class="dirty"><input name="checkLangs[0].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>English</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="checkLangs_1__Name" name="checkLangs[1].Name" type="hidden" value="Deutsch">
        <input id="checkLangs_1__LanguageId" name="checkLangs[1].LanguageId" type="hidden" value="2">
        <input checked="checked" id="checkLangs_1__isChecked" name="checkLangs[1].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" class="dirty"><input name="checkLangs[1].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>Deutsch</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="checkLangs_2__Name" name="checkLangs[2].Name" type="hidden" value="Español">
        <input id="checkLangs_2__LanguageId" name="checkLangs[2].LanguageId" type="hidden" value="3">
        <input checked="checked" id="checkLangs_2__isChecked" name="checkLangs[2].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="checkLangs[2].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>Español</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="checkLangs_3__Name" name="checkLangs[3].Name" type="hidden" value="Français">
        <input id="checkLangs_3__LanguageId" name="checkLangs[3].LanguageId" type="hidden" value="4">
        <input checked="checked" id="checkLangs_3__isChecked" name="checkLangs[3].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="checkLangs[3].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>Français</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="checkLangs_4__Name" name="checkLangs[4].Name" type="hidden" value="Português">
        <input id="checkLangs_4__LanguageId" name="checkLangs[4].LanguageId" type="hidden" value="5">
        <input checked="checked" id="checkLangs_4__isChecked" name="checkLangs[4].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="checkLangs[4].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>Português</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="checkLangs_5__Name" name="checkLangs[5].Name" type="hidden" value="Pусский">
        <input id="checkLangs_5__LanguageId" name="checkLangs[5].LanguageId" type="hidden" value="6">
        <input id="checkLangs_5__isChecked" name="checkLangs[5].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="checkLangs[5].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>Pусский</label>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you adding inline `onchange` as well as adding the events via jQuery, please pick one and stick with it. I would recommend not using inline.

Comment: `$("#id selector")` -> "selector" is a *child* element.   Your secondary inputs are not *children* of the #langCheck, so that selector won't work.  **Always test your selectors** - ie `console.log($('#langcheck input:checkbox').length)` if it's zero, it's the selector that's not working (*at the time it runs*), not the .change or the code inside the event.

Comment: If the attempt and the problem are entirely HTML/JavaScript, can you provide a runnable [mcve] using HTML/JavaScript instead of this server-side code?

Comment: Change `$('#langcheck input:checkbox').change(function...` to `$(document).on("change", "input:checkbox:not(#langCheck)", function...` - given the HTML you have, would be better to make other changes such as adding a class to your other checkboxes or the `<td>` they're contained within - and it would be better to move your js code to the end so that you don't need event delegation.

Comment: If you changed your `$('#langcheck input:checkbox')` to just `console.log($('input:checkbox').length)` it would still only give 1 as your script runs before the other elements exist.  Move the script to the end or wrap it in doc.ready   Note: your controls are generated server-side rather than "dynamically" which, in js parlance, means they're created by js after the page has loaded, which is not the case here.

Comment: You'll (clearly) also need to change the second `$('#langcheck input:checkbox')`

Comment: Please provide your *rendered* HTML and then someone will likely provide a solution quite quickly.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a js dev, but my client wants me to finish this as well, so what can I do. I posted the rendered code in the question. Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial issue with your code of

```
$('#langcheck input:checkbox')
```

is because "selectorselector" is a *child* selector, which is not appropriate here as #langCheck is an `input` so does not have any child elements.

Giving each language checkbox the same class makes *everything* much easier:

```
<input class="langCheck" name="checkLangs[5].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

these can then all be referenced/selected via the class and all changed in one go, eg:

```
$(".langCheck").prop("checked", true);
```

(with a change to the all to `id=allLangCheck` to distinguish it)

You then add a change event on "*all*" to change all and a change event on each of the others to change the "all".

Updated snippet:

```js
$("#allLangCheck").on("change", function() {      
  $(".langCheck").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});

$(".langCheck").on("change", function() {
  $("#allLangCheck").prop("checked", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="allLangCheck" name="AllLangsChecked" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <input name="AllLangsChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>Sichtbar in allen Sprachen</label>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="checkLangs_0__Name" name="checkLangs[0].Name" type="hidden" value="English">
        <input id="checkLangs_0__LanguageId" name="checkLangs[0].LanguageId" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input checked="checked" id="checkLangs_0__isChecked" name="checkLangs[0].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" class="langCheck dirty"><input name="checkLangs[0].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>English</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="checkLangs_1__Name" name="checkLangs[1].Name" type="hidden" value="Deutsch">
        <input id="checkLangs_1__LanguageId" name="checkLangs[1].LanguageId" type="hidden" value="2">
        <input checked="checked" id="checkLangs_1__isChecked" name="checkLangs[1].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" class="langCheck dirty"><input name="checkLangs[1].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>Deutsch</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="checkLangs_2__Name" name="checkLangs[2].Name" type="hidden" value="Español">
        <input id="checkLangs_2__LanguageId" name="checkLangs[2].LanguageId" type="hidden" value="3">
        <input checked="checked" id="checkLangs_2__isChecked" name="checkLangs[2].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" class='langCheck'><input name="checkLangs[2].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>Español</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="checkLangs_3__Name" name="checkLangs[3].Name" type="hidden" value="Français">
        <input id="checkLangs_3__LanguageId" name="checkLangs[3].LanguageId" type="hidden" value="4">
        <input checked="checked" id="checkLangs_3__isChecked" name="checkLangs[3].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" class='langCheck'><input name="checkLangs[3].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>Français</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="checkLangs_4__Name" name="checkLangs[4].Name" type="hidden" value="Português">
        <input id="checkLangs_4__LanguageId" name="checkLangs[4].LanguageId" type="hidden" value="5">
        <input checked="checked" id="checkLangs_4__isChecked" name="checkLangs[4].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" class='langCheck'><input name="checkLangs[4].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>Português</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="checkLangs_5__Name" name="checkLangs[5].Name" type="hidden" value="Pусский">
        <input id="checkLangs_5__LanguageId" name="checkLangs[5].LanguageId" type="hidden" value="6">
        <input id="checkLangs_5__isChecked" name="checkLangs[5].isChecked" type="checkbox" value="true" class='langCheck'><input name="checkLangs[5].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label>Pусский</label>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you so far. I tried to replicate all you did, and I think i understood. However, now my system is doing the opposite:
the first checkbox is "uncheckable". so whenever i check it, it immediately unchecks itself. and the other checkboxes get CHECKED if i check my first one (that then unchecks itself), but ofc i want the opposite: if i check the first checkbox, the other checkboxes get unchecked. and if i  check any of the checkboxes with the language to it, the top checkbox gets unchecked. i think we are close tho!

Comment: nevermind. i fixed it myself. the function should be:                                    $("#allLangCheck").on("change", function () {
                                        $(".langCheck").prop("checked", false);
                                    });

                                    $(".langCheck").on("change", function () {
                                        $("#allLangCheck").prop("checked", false);
                                    });